# Bend rectangle along its long axis

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create a 3D model of a **Penrose triangle**

[image: penrose triangle]

different angle of a 3D Penrose triangle
[image: different angle]

I am currently following the obvious path which is 3 rectangles with lowered edges at the ends to make them fit with the rest. But as you can see in the second image, the rectangles are rotated/bent on their long axis. How can that be achieved on Blender?

Comment: What about rotating the face on one end?

Answer (score 2):

The key point to an optical illusion is that it is an **"optical illusion"** and you usually can't model them accurately. You should create a model that looks right from the camera, but may not look right as you rotate around the model.

For the triangle you are doing [look at this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svi83TBDryI)

A tip that can help is to use the Blender Internal for rendering. Under the Options panel of the material there is an Invert Z Depth setting. I haven't tried doing the same in cycles.

This scene -

[image]

renders as this -

[image]

I believe this was created by Ton back in blender 1.70, you get a copy of [the file here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34014)